# Using Select by Attribute with multiple layers in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: layers, attribute-table, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to find "Signal" in a field named "Maintained by" but there are quite a few layers.

I do not want to go into every single layer and change "Signal" to "Private."

Does anyone know a quick shortcut?

Comment: You have all layers added to the map?

Answer (score 2):

You can use arcpy. I'm assuming you have all layers you want to change added to the map and no others. Execute the code in the python window.

```
import arcpy

fieldname = 'Maintained by'
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps("Map")[0]
for lyr in m.listLayers():
    sql = """{0} = 'Signal'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyr,fieldname))

    #First try this and make sure correct rows are selected:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=lyr, where_clause=sql)

    #Then unselect all, remove row above and execute everything including code below
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyr,fieldname,sql) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0]='Private'
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```